# Is it possible to use PyTorch's `BatchNorm1d` with `BCELossWithLogits`?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, multilabel-classification, cross-entropy

I am attempting to normalize the outputs of my classifier that uses `BCELossWithLogits` as part of its loss function. As far as I know, this implements Sigmoid function internally and outputs the loss.

I want to normalize the output of the sigmoid function prior to calculating the loss. Is it possible to use `BatchNorm1d` with `BCELossWithLogits`? Or is passing the output tensor to `torch.sigmoid` to `BatchNorm1d` and separately calculating `BCELoss` the only possible solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#bceloss) instead of [`BCELossWithLogits`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#bcewithlogitsloss) which is described as:

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain Sigmoid followed by a BCELoss

For example,

```
m = nn.Sigmoid()
bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(3)
loss = nn.BCELoss()
input = torch.randn((2, 3), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.empty(2, 3).random_(2)
output = loss(m(bn(input)), target)
output.backward()
```